# When volume is consider as fundamenta quantity instead of length what difficulties occur

Tags: homework-and-exercises

When volume is consider as fundamental quantity instead of length what difficulties occur?

Comment: What does it mean to be a "fundamental quantity"?

Comment: This definitely needs more context

Comment: Fundamental means based quantity

Comment: So are you asking what would happen if there was an SI base unit of volume instead of length?

Comment: Assuming you know how to measure angles, you can go from volumes to lengths and vice versa.

Comment: Well, it makes it much more convoluted to conceptualize for one thing...  I'd rather not measure distance in $\sqrt[3]{Litres}$

Comment: @jacob1729 How do you define angles, and a way to measure them, without using lengths?

Comment: @JMac Measuring lengths in *seconds* is perfectly logical in relativity, using the speed of light as a natural universal "conversion factor". And there is no problem in CGS units with the unit of charge having dimensions $\sqrt{\strut\text{gm}\cdot\text{cm}}$.

Comment: @alephzero my comment was made thinking about symplectic structures that define areas but not lengths or angles. I guess that a metric space is a structure with lengths but since they are not necessarily inner product spaces they have no angles. But agreed that a space with only angles just seems weird.

Comment: @alephzero Measuring lengths in seconds still seems fundamentally very different than measuring lengths in volumes, which are more directly related to lengths already.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean volume in the "usual" sense, of dimensions $\text{length}^3$? Sure, let's do it, let's move to the volume being the "fundamental" quantity and give it units of $[\text{SMM}]$. How do you define a length element then? the units would have to be $[\text{SMM}]^{1/3}$, and an area would have to have units of $[\text{SMM}]^{2/3}$ not very practical for everyday life...

Also, the units for the "fundamental" quantity length in , e.g. SI units, is determined by the distance light travels in $\sim \frac{1}{3\times10^8}$ seconds. You will have to come up with a way to define your "fundamental" volume in your base/using other SI units which is easier than the above...